# How to deal with SQL Server from native C++ on the Windows platform?

Tags: c++, sql-server, database

Is there any solution other than the ugly ADO as it is not good and badly documented?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, we used the DTL library and were relatively happy with it.

SOCI looks like something deserving attention too. I never used it, though.

Comment: I second the bit about SOCI, its a pretty good library and it has a fairly active community.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the Qt toolkit, it provides an SQL interface that can talk to different database backends (including MS-SQL via ODBC).

[QSql](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qtsql.html)

[Supported drivers](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/sql-driver.html)

cheers,
mitch

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sqlncli.dll library, but is a ugly method.

Answer (score 0):

Give my [CSQLBinding](http://networkdls.com/Software.Asp?Review=70) class a shot. It handles most everything for you.